# Custom Listview with Radio Group scrolling issue

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to implement a custom listview containing radio buttons, but when I scroll the listview the selected radio button gets deselected automatically.I worked around but I am unable to figure out the exact issue. I am new here.
My Adapter Class code is

```
 public class CustomAdapterListView extends ArrayAdapter<FDetailsPOJO> {

    private final List<FDetailsPOJO> list;
    private final Activity context;
    int resource;
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    public CustomAdapterListView(Activity context, int resource, List<FDetailsPOJO> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.list = objects;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            try {

                convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_checkbox_row, parent, false);

                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

                viewHolder.tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.custom_checkbox_row_tv);
                viewHolder.radioGroup = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fragmenttab2_options);

                viewHolder.rbYes = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fragmenttab2_options_yes);
                viewHolder.rbNo = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fragmenttab2_options_no);

                viewHolder.radioGroup.setTag(position);
                convertView.setTag(R.id.custom_checkbox_row_tv, viewHolder.tvName);
                convertView.setTag(R.id.fragmenttab2_options, viewHolder.radioGroup);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                int isChecked = (int) group.getTag();
                try {

                    switch (checkedId) {
                        case R.id.fragmenttab2_options_yes:
                            try {
                                list.get(isChecked).setCheckedYes(true);
                                list.get(isChecked).setCheckedNo(false);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            break;
                        case R.id.fragmenttab2_options_no:
                            try {
                                list.get(isChecked).setCheckedNo(true);
                                list.get(isChecked).setCheckedYes(false);

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            break;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        try {
            viewHolder.radioGroup.setTag(position);
            viewHolder.tvName.setText(list.get(position).getFitnessItem());
            viewHolder.rbYes.setChecked(list.get(position).isCheckedYes());
            viewHolder.rbNo.setChecked(list.get(position).isCheckedNo());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvName;
        RadioGroup radioGroup;
        RadioButton rbYes;
        RadioButton rbNo;
    }
}
```

While searching for solution I found a code snippet which solves the issue but that is not the appropriate way as mentioned in the same link

```
 @Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's running through the lines inside the second `try` block and not just triggering an exception? Just to rule out usual suspects

Comment: Yes. It works fine without try catch as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep track of selected radio option in separate variable and mark it selected likewise as per the values in getView method of the list manually.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a List or Map to record the status of each radio button in adapter. When onCheckedChanged method called, save current radio button's state into List or Map, and set the check state of each radio button according to the List or Map in getView method.

Comment: I am already preserving the state of selected radio button by using setCheckedYes(); method and changing its value in onCheckedChanged method. Even I get the appropriate value in getView method after scrolling but I found that  `viewHolder.rbYes.setChecked(list.get(position).isCheckedYes()); ` is not working. The radio button gets deselected.